# Why is there a need for other coordinate systems?

Tags: terminology, dimension-theory-analysis

I have been wondering a lot about this. I have just reached A-Levels, and I have chosen the course Further Math. In class, we were talking about the Parallel coordinate system, but I didn't really see a need for it. I went home and did some research, but I couldn't find anything. I know the need for a 3D coordinate system, but other than that nothing!

Comment: No, I am asking for the reason behind the existence of other coordinate systems

Comment: Because some information is more easily expressed, and easier to calculate with in other coordinate systems. In Cartesian coordinates the equation of a sphere is fairly simple: $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2$. But in spherical coordinates, it is trivial: $\rho = R$. If you are dealing with something where you are only interested in how far you are from a fixed point, then spherical coordinates are going to be a much easier choice. In calculus, using polar or spherical coordinates can make some calculations that are extremely difficult in cartesian coordinates very easy.

Comment: I understand thanks!